# How to format float 0.5 to float 0.50

Tags: javascript

Update:
Seem like their bug. 
Github issue link:
https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/10491

=================

I am studying FreeCodeCamp course-"Exact Change".
I need to convert float-type-data 0.5 to float-type-data 0.50, I have try some solutions but not work!

float.toFixed(2) return a string-type "0.50", and if I use parseFloat("0.50") it will return float-type-data 0.5!

How can i solve this issue?

Follow is the requirement screenshot, I had try float 0.5, but failed to pass!

[image]

Comment: Why do you need 0.50 as float?

Comment: Isn't 0.5 === 0.50? Just use `.toFixed` when you need to output something, in other cases it doesn't matter for you if it 0.5 or 0.50

Comment: A variation of this question is asked at least once every week. Is there no canonical duplicate?

Comment: @JJJ I haven't found one, if you can find, do tell, we'll mark it.

Comment: @Natiq See the picture. Seems like their bug.

Comment: You have some other problem elsewhere in the code. I tried it by having it return a static `[["QUARTER", 0.5]]` and that specific test passed. http://i.imgur.com/6STygpP.png You should post your entire code.

Comment: @JJJ thanks for reply. I had pass it. The bug related to Float-precise subject, eg: 0.2 display as 0.199999.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight misconception about numbers in JavaScript.

JavaScript numbers do not have trailing zeroes after the decimal point. If the requirement was to get `0.50` displayed on the screen, then it must be the string `"0.50"`, and not the number, `0.5`.

Comment: The requirement on their web is   [["QUARTER", 0.50]] . I had try [["QUARTER", 0.5]] and [["QUARTER", "0.50"]] , failed to passed. You can see it on their web: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/exact-change

Comment: @Bob Could you post a link to the specific question/challenge on their site?

Answer (score 0):

Only string will have a value in decimal with **0** in the end. when it becomes a number, the **0** will be removed automatically when it's in the end of the decimal place.

Comment: but i cannot pass if return float 0.5~~see the picture